# Hide div hovering and show another down with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I happen to have a div and I would like hovering above would make a hover effect and would show another div the same size and characteristics but with other content. I've tried with jquery does not work, do not know if I'll be doing something wrong, here I leave the code:

jquery:

```
$(function() {
          $('.ep1-d').hover(function() {
            $('.div-titulos-ep-singles-d').fadeIn(); 
          }, function() {
            $('.div-titulos-ep-singles-d').fadeOut();
          });
        });
```

html:

```
  <div class="ep1-d">

    prueba-cambia
      </div>

       <div class="div-titulos-ep-singles-d">
      <span class="titulos-ep-y-singles-texto-d">
    prueba<br>
    <br>
    prueba<br>
    prueba<br>
    9<br>
    </span>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.div-titulos-ep-singles-d {
    height: 260px;
    width: 260px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 465px;
    top: 46px;

}

.ep1-d {
    height: 260px;
    width: 260px;
    position:absolute;
    left: 465px;
    top: 46px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24)!important;
```

Comment: you are using same class in `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` ??

Comment: I'm not very up to date with jquery, please, could you show me the solution?

Comment: no its right nothing wrong with that just wanted to confirm this from your side

Comment: The strange thing is that it shows directly div div-titles-ep-singles-d and the other is not

Comment: see my answer and follow the link, made a few changes. hope it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and along with the jquery that you are using

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.ep1-d').hover(function() {
             $('.div-titulos-ep-singles-d').fadeIn('slow');
         }, function() {
             $('.div-titulos-ep-singles-d').fadeOut('slow');
         });
    });
```

for example **[visit here](https://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/L9kmh36e/1/)**

### New edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var $interval  = "";
        $('.ep1-d').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
          $interval =  setInterval(function(){
                 $('.div-titulos-ep-singles-d').fadeIn("slow").promise().done(function(){
                     $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                 });
            },20) 
        }).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
            clearInterval($interval);
        });
   });
```

for example **[visit here](https://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/L9kmh36e/2/)**

Comment: If you look when the mouse is over does fade in fade out 3 times. I think there's something wrong.

Comment: I think that does not work, if you look when the mouse stays flashing. : O

Comment: no its working great over here, other than that if you are facing any problem with changing mouse cursor you can customize it to become a hover cursor with code inside hover effect

Comment: I think there's an error when displaying the div. Your first presented should have z-indez = 2? D Or-div-singles titles-ep-must hide with CSS? I think that could also be a problem, appear the two div.

Comment: what your suggesting you should try it

Comment: Ok sorry, I was wrong testing, works perfect, I had not seen that in the CSS had hidden the second div. I'm sorry. Now the problem is that flashes three times, I think there is an error in the fade in fade out, to see if you can look Meenesh

Comment: did you - jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/L9kmh36e/2  visit this link, it continues blinking with no limit try this code works great for me

Comment: Sorry for my English, I am using the translator google: D
To me, in the example you put me on the web that has happened to me, by placing the mouse cursor over the div I flashes three times, I've tried on my website and it is the same: _S

Comment: its ok, your messages are understood, i made the code with a interval which fires in every .2 seconds but to see that you need to visit this fiddle it will work continues  http://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/L9kmh36e/2, the code works for me, with unlimited blinks

Comment: And as I remove the flicker?I forgive but I'm rolling.

Comment: Meenesh Jain All I need is hovering above the "EP1-d" appears with a fade effect "div-titles-ep-singles-d" and to remove the mouse cursor over to reappear with a fade effect "EP1-d". See if you understand me now.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go mate. following code should work for you ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>checking</title>
        <style>

            #div1 {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background: red;
            }

            #div2 {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background: green;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#div1").hover(function() {
                    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
                    $("#div2").fadeIn(2000);
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The effect does not fade out, it is because the div div-titles-ep-singles-d :_(

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('.ep1-d').hover(function() {
             $('.div-titulos-ep-singles-d').fadeIn(1000);
         }, function() {
             $('.div-titulos-ep-singles-d').fadeOut(1500);
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/1wyjzyz6/4/

A smooth fade-in fade-out transition on hover effect

```
.divOne , .divTwo{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: wheat;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   transition: opacity 2s;
}

.divTwo {
   background-color: pink;
   opacity: 0;
}

.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadeIn {
    opacity: 1;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.outDiv').hover(     
        function () {
          $(".divOne").addClass("fadeOut");
          $(".divTwo").addClass("fadeIn"); 
        }, 
        function () {
          $(".divOne").removeClass("fadeOut");
          $(".divTwo").removeClass("fadeIn"); 
        }
    );
});
```